# µTorrent mentions that I don't have enough space, but I do?

Tags: file-management, filesystems, utorrent

I am trying to download a 4.8 GiB DVD ISO image over bit torrent, but µTorrent is giving me an error that I do not have enough space. I didn't believe it at first so I checked for myself and I definitely have enough space, over 60 GiB left:

[image]

Comment: Please, µ! </petpeeve>

Comment: @jt I can now fix this for you! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is due to a limitation with the FAT32 filesystem and not uTorrent, to fix this you can simply convert your existing filesystem to NTFS via the command line `convert` tool like so:

```
convert c: /FS:NTFS
```

I don't really see any disadvantages this could bring you, only advantages, lots of them.

With FAT32, the max file size is limited to just shy of 4 GB. With NTFS, you are limited to 16 TiB, theoretically it could support 16 EiB, but this is a restriction with the implementation.

You can find a good comparison chart of various file systems [here](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm).

Comment: "I don't really see any disadvantages this could bring you, only advantages, lots of them." Note that automated partition conversion doesn't work as well as reformatting with a new filesystem; converting is not as flexible, and imposes some unusual requirements (particularly on cluster size, if I'm remembering right).

Comment: been looking to solve this for very long time thanks!

Comment: Some media players like my DVD player and my PS3 won't read an external hard drive unless it is in FAT32. Just thought I'd note that in the "any disadvantages" column, as it is a big one to me :)

Comment: @Paolo, I'll hope your c: drive isn't FAT32.

Comment: How long is `convert c: /FS:NTFS` supposed to run?